# Computing an Integral by means of measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to compute the integral $$\int _0 ^ \infty xe^{-kx} dx,  \,k\geq1$$ by means of measure theory. Integration by parts will not work here. Also I used the Taylor series of the exponential function with the idea in mind to use the fact that for positive functions one can interchange sum symbol and integral, but it did not lead me further.

I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "measure theoretical means"? And why doesn't integration by parts work here?

Comment: maybe you can use the sequence of functions defined by $$f_n(x):=\chi_{[0,n)}(x)\, x\left(1-\frac{kx}{n}\right)^n$$ It is just an idea

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $$\int_0^\infty x e^{-kx}\; dx = - \frac{d}{dk} \int_0^\infty e^{-kx}\; dx $$
Use "measure theoretical means" to justify the interchange of derivative and integral.

Comment: Thanks, but $k$ is a constant and not a variable.

Comment: Don't be afraid to turn your constants into variables.